# In postgresql How to get all rows that ends with 1?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
id name  length
1   A     21.5
2   B     12.4
3   C      0
4   D     17
5   E      1
```

I wish to get:

```
id name  length
1   A     21.5
5   E      1
```

Meaning all rows that hase length that ends up with 1.

length is a `numeric` column.

It's very simple thing to do with programing languages but it seems quite not natural for SQL. How can I do that efficiently and simply? 
My only thought is to convert the field to `Text` and then lose eveything after the `.` then convert it to array and choose the letter in the position of array length.  This will probebly work but it seems like a very bad solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`FLOOR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html) and modulo division:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE FLOOR(length) % 10 = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/44327/1/0)**</kbd>